Fill a field inside dialog after return of method call
I want to fill the Conclusion field after I click on Copy Notes button. How to do this in Odoo? I tried using the value property in the returned data but nothing happened.
@api.multi
def copy_notes(self):
    notes = ""
    if self.uuid_v4 == 'e3d2e0c7-ba64-4522-abf3-9befcf2bdacc':
        if self.physical_examination_id.id:
            notes = "Physical Examination"
            notes = notes + ("\n" if notes and self.physical_examination_id.eyes_remark else "")
            #do many things here that is not relevant to the question
            self.note = notes
    else:
        raise ValidationError(_("This exam cannot copy notes"))
    return {
        'value': {'note': notes},
        'type': "ir.actions.do_nothing",
        }


